# How to Change Odoo print menu label?

Tags: user-interface, odoo, odoo-10

[I am working in Odoo 10 and i want to change print menu label as i am unable to find them in edit form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utoJJ.png)

[Sample Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utoJJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Go to > Settings > Reports > Reports (find invoices)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Custom reports can be configured in reports folder of our custom module.

If you need to change the report name of existing odoo application, navigate to addons folder, find the respective module and open reports folder.

You can open the xml file and change the string value in report tag.